# Bitbucket pipeline chromedriver 'exited abnormally'

Tags: selenium-webdriver, automation, protractor, e2e-testing, bitbucket-pipelines

I have an e2e bitbucket pipeline that runs fine until the test execution,  then I get the following error:

```
    [18:04:37] I/local - Starting selenium standalone server...[18:04:39] I/local - Selenium standalone server started at http://(theIPaddress)/wd/hub
[18:05:40] E/launcher - unknown error: Chrome failed to start: exited abnormally
  (Driver info: chromedriver=2.35.528139 (47ead77cb35ad2a9a83248b292151462a66cd881),platform=Linux 4.14.48-coreos-r2 x86_64) (WARNING: The server did not provide any stacktrace information)
Command duration or timeout: 60.14 seconds
Build info: version: '3.13.0', revision: '2f0d292', time: '2018-06-25T15:32:19.891Z'
System info: host: '048a3785-1927-4192-a52e-37b3698562ff', ip: '10.252.102.207', os.name: 'Linux', os.arch: 'amd64', os.version: '4.14.48-coreos-r2', java.version: '1.8.0_171'
Driver info: driver.version: unknown
[18:05:40] E/launcher - WebDriverError: unknown error: Chrome failed to start: exited abnormally
```

When scrolling down I see this

```
E/launcher - Process exited with error code 199
npm ERR! code ELIFECYCLE
npm ERR! errno 199
npm ERR! protractor-typescript-cucumber@3.0.0 test: `protractor typeScript/config/config.js`
npm ERR! Exit status 199
npm ERR! 
npm ERR! Failed at the protractor-typescript-cucumber@3.0.0 test script.
```

Everything works fine on my local machine. Has anyone run into this error?

Comment: Okay, so now I see that the build never starts with executing pipeline commands in a queue, but when executing them in separate steps, build starts, but the test doesn't.

Comment: Try out the latest ChromeDriver (2.40).

Comment: But the tests run perfectly in my local machine with my current versions...

Comment: Are there differences in ChromeDriver and Chrome versions between your environment and your pipeline?